# Can't find syntax error in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

Chrome dev tools is telling me there is an error on line 3 but I am unsure what it is. Admittedly I am new to coding with jQuery so it's possible that the tutorials that I followed had something wrong.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.carcraft.atsbusinessandgames.com/xmls/carcraft_1-7-10Test.xml',
    type: "Get",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (result) {
        }
        $(result).find('Module').each(function() {
            //$("#ModsList").append($(this).text());
            var authors = $(this).find('authors').text();
            var version = $(this).find('version').text();
            var date = $(this).find('date').text();
            var episode = $(this).find('episode').text();
            $("#ModsList").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + $authors + "</td>" + "<td>" + $version + "</td>" + "<td>" + $date + "</td>" + "<td>" + $episode + "</td>" + "</tr>");
        });
    error: function() {
    alert("Notify the site owner that the xml file has a syntax error and is therefore unreadable.");
    }
});
```

This is the table I'm trying to modify via above code:

```
<table id="ModsList">

    <tr style="font-weight: bold;">

         <td>Mod Name</td>

         <td>Author(s)</td>

         <td>Version</td>

         <td>Date added/updated</td>

         <td>Episode Added</td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: which line is 3?also why use `$authors` when you only have `authors` ?

Comment: please post the error  which you are getting

Comment: Your success callback is closed incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `success` handler is not declared appropriately.  You have to put the code in between the `{  }` for the success function.  As you have it now, you're inserting random code into an object definition, which is not legal.

Change the code to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.carcraft.atsbusinessandgames.com/xmls/carcraft_1-7-10Test.xml',
    type: "Get",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (result) {
        $(result).find('Module').each(function() {
            //$("#ModsList").append($(this).text());
            var authors = $(this).find('authors').text();
            var version = $(this).find('version').text();
            var date = $(this).find('date').text();
            var episode = $(this).find('episode').text();
            $("#ModsList").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + authors + "</td>" + "<td>" + version + "</td>" + "<td>" + date + "</td>" + "<td>"+episode+"</td>" + "</tr>");
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Notify the site owner that the xml file has a syntax error and is therefore unreadable.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.carcraft.atsbusinessandgames.com/xmls/carcraft_1-7-10Test.xml',
    type: "Get",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (result) {

        $(result).find('Module').each(function() {
            //$("#ModsList").append($(this).text());
            var authors = $(this).find('authors').text();
            var version = $(this).find('version').text();
            var date = $(this).find('date').text();
            var episode = $(this).find('episode').text();
            $("#ModsList").append("<tr>" + "<td>" +authors+ "</td>" + "<td>" +version+ "</td>" + "<td>" +date +"</td>" + "<td>" +episode+ "</td>" + "</tr>");
        });
},
    failure: function() {
    alert("Notify the site owner that the xml file has a syntax error and is therefore unreadable.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why success: function (result) {} is being empty? Hope the result should be accessible only at success function.